# Using Case Function to make NULL values appear as blank

Tags: cognos-10

I keep getting error that my Case Function is incorrect. My goal is to use the  Case Function to make every NULL or '0' values appear as blank. Incompatible data types in case statement is the prompt that I get when running it in report studio. Example of the table would be this. WCPDOD is an Integer, WCPDOD 9int,null)

```
WCPDOD     POLICY   CLAIM NUMBER
19741020   2001A    123456N000040
20040101   2003A    456789001531
20021220   00594        123456
20040507   2003A    2222043621
20040517   2003I    90043625

CASE 
WHEN [WCPDOD] = '0' THEN ' '
WHEN [WCPDOD] IS NULL THEN ' '
ELSE [WCPDOD]
END
```

Comment: what type is `WCPDOD`?

Comment: "Incompatible data types in case statement" is not a SQL Server error.

Comment: Yes because it is an error encountered in Report Studio - Cognos 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `WCPDOD` is an integer, you shouldn't compare it to string literals such as `'0'`, but to numeric literals, such as `0`. More importantly, different branches of your `case` statement return different types - the first two return strings (the `' '` literal) and the `else` branch returns an `integer`. You should cast it to a string:

```
CASE 
WHEN [WCPDOD] = 0 THEN ' '
WHEN [WCPDOD] IS NULL THEN ' '
ELSE CAST ([WCPDOD] AS VARCHAR(40))
END
```

Comment: Question. Why do I need to use Varchar? If the data is neither blank or NULL then I expect integer results right? So why do I have to use ELSE CAST ([WCPDOD] AS VARCHAR(40))

Comment: All the branches of a `case` statement should return the same datatype (in part, so they can all be put in the same column). Since some of the branches return `varchar` results, all of them should, so you need the cast.